# FLEX - Adding multiple images in FOR loop

Tags: image, apache-flex, load

I seem to have a problem here, loading in multiple images in a FOR loop.

This is my code:

I'm reading an XML file to get the location of the thumbnails I need to add.
Then I go through the whole list (for now I go through the first 5 elements) and add them to my TileGroup named "popUpImgGroup".

For some reason I only get 1 visible thumb, but there are in fact being added 5 elements.

Any idea?

Thanks! :)

```
private function loadPopUpThumbs():void{
            for(var i:int=1; i<=5; i++){
                var thumbImg:Image = new Image();
                var _loader:Loader = new Loader();

                _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event):void{ 
                    thumbImg.source = e.currentTarget.content;
                });
                _loader.load(new URLRequest(encodeURI(popUpXMLList.(attribute('nr')==i.toString()).@thumbURL)));

                popUpImgGroup.addElement(thumbImg);

                thumbImg.width = 90;
                thumbImg.height = 90;
                thumbImg.scaleMode = "letterbox";
                thumbImg.verticalAlign = "bottom";
                thumbImg.smooth = true;
                thumbImg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(evt:MouseEvent){ popUpThumbClicked(popUpXMLList.(attribute('nr')==i.toString()).@fullURL)});

                trace("Thumb added: " + popUpXMLList.(attribute('nr')==i.toString()).@thumbURL);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you see the last thumb or the first one?  You aren't giving the thumbImg an x or y position. Are all the thumbs displaying on top of each other?  In most cases; you do not want to add images like this as every image you add will be renderered.  For large amounts there will be noticable slowdown in your app.  It is much better to use a List based class which will only render the displayed items; instead of everything on the list.

Comment: They are added to a TileGroup, which automaticly positions them in a grid. I see the second image, on the spot where the 5th should be.

What I need to do is load in the thumbnails (which is what I'm trying to do here). Full res will be loaded later when the user clicks them.

Comment: All I need is to load a number of thumbs from xml file(that part works), and display them in this list. They also need to have a function trigger when you click the thumbs. EDIT: Hmm, now I see the first image on thumbnail, but the last image on fullRes

Any other way to do this would also be nice :) As long as it works and looks clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer -.-

I hate it when I struggle with a solution, and post a question here only to figure it out right after. Sorry to bother you guys =) Heres what I ended up doing:

```
            private function loadPopUpThumbs():void{
            if(curThumbImg <= totThumbImg){
                var thumbImg:Image = new Image();
                var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
                var imageNr:int = curThumbImg;

                _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,function(e:Event):void{ 
                    thumbImg.source = e.currentTarget.content;

                    popUpImgGroup.addElement(thumbImg);

                    thumbImg.width = 90;
                    thumbImg.height = 90;
                    thumbImg.scaleMode = "letterbox";
                    thumbImg.verticalAlign = "bottom";
                    thumbImg.smooth = true;
                    thumbImg.id = "thumbImg" + imageNr;
                    thumbImg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(evt:MouseEvent):void{ popUpThumbClicked(popUpXMLList.(attribute('nr')==imageNr.toString()).@fullURL)});

                    trace("Thumb added: " + popUpXMLList.(attribute('nr')==imageNr.toString()).@thumbURL);
                    curThumbImg++;
                    loadPopUpThumbs();
                });

                _loader.load(new URLRequest(encodeURI(popUpXMLList.(attribute('nr')==imageNr.toString()).@thumbURL)));

            }else{
                trace("DONE Adding thubs!!!");
            }
        }
```